# Can you record games on YouTube TV with NFL Sunday Ticket?

Tags: youtube

Is there a way to record an NFL Game and watch it later on YouTube TV?  Basically, I want to record the game and have the ability to fast forward through commercials.  I am happy to subscribe to the NFL Sunday Ticket package, but must be able to record games and watch them at my leisure.  Otherwise, the NFL is unbearable to watch.

Comment: You are probably right.  Let me clarify.  The season opens this weekend, maybe someone could answer this on Sunday?  I just want to know if you can record NFL games that are shown on NFL Sunday ticket and if you can fast forward through the commercials like you once could on Direct TV.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears if you have Sunday Ticket you can record games using YouTube TV, even if you don’t have monthly YouTube TV subscription. As this is the first weekend of games, I have obviously not attempted this yet but it does look like it’s possible.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/13821595?hl=en#zippy=%2Ci-want-to-share-nfl-sunday-ticket-with-my-family

An excerpt from the Google support website (further directions for downloading and recording can be found by clicking the link):

“Record NFL games
You get unlimited digital video recording (DVR) storage with NFL Sunday Ticket on YouTube. But to record games and watch your recordings, you need to go to the YouTube TV app. DVR is available for NFL Sunday Ticket Primetime Channel subscribers through YouTube TV, even without a monthly YouTube TV Base Plan subscription.”